# How to do Performance Improvement for Multi tenacy with Shared Database and Shared Schema Approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am in the process of building Multi-Tenant using Shared Database and Shared Schema Approach.

Initially, I have 5 separate databases when I execute a stored procedure on these DB I will get results faster around 1 sec. I executed the same sp in the Multi-tenant DB. I got results around 5 to 6 seconds.

I know single db has only few records in the table. In Multi-tenant DB has multiple tenant data. so I am getting the results slower.

I already introduced enough indexes for the tenantId column.

My question is how to optimize my multi-tenant DB to get faster results.

Kindly suggest me any performance improvement solution either to the whole DB or at least for tables with millions of records.

Note: I am not able to share you the execution plan or sql query due to permission.

Comment: Somewhat of a broad question, no query, no query plans, no schema.

Comment: I have lot of SP's and views involved. I tried to take an execution plan of an SP but again the sp generated around 20 execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a specific query that you wish to optimize. Examine the execution plan. Create any indexes that the plan indicates are missing.

Do the same for all the queries you wish to optimize.

Comment: Is it possible to do any optimization at the Database Level

Comment: It might be possible to re-design your database to make your queries simpler and therefore faster, but that is a broad topic, and I'm sure that's not what you meant.   There's no magic button.   Performance optimization is a tedious, detail-oriented process.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on dba.stackexchange.com to see if there are any DBA-owned things that can be done, regarding checking for corrupt indexes, disk issues, etc.   This site is for answers from a developer's standpoint.